# Calling a setter in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables, properties, setter

Let's assume that we have a property in a Objective-C class. And we have synthesized it in the implementation file. Thus a setter and a getter are generated. We may call the property's getter by writing `self.variable` or `[self variable]`. We can also call the setter like this
`[self.variable setVariable: value];` but what if we write `self.variable = value;` what is called in this situation is it the setter or is it something else for example the `operator = function`.

Thank you;

Comment: BTW, there is no longer a need for explicitly calling @Synthize unless one needs to control the underlying ivar name and make it something other than the default which is the property name pre-pended with a "_".

Comment: but since when is that? iOS 7 ?

Comment: Since iOS 4 and Xcode 4.4. See Objective-C [Feature Availability](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/index.html) Index. Also no need to declare ivars or pre-declare methods and the order of methods no longer makes a difference. All that makes for very small header files, only the public interface needs to be in it. Even IBActions and IBOutlets can be in the implementation file (.m) only.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of

`self.variable = value;`

`[self setVariable:value]`

is called.

Answer (score 2):

self.variable = value calls the setter.